# How to differentiate between two integers without equality operators?

Tags: c, integer, max, min

Given two integers, how can I differentiate between the two integers, maximum, minimum and equality without using if statements or selections (>=, >, and =). I thought about using `fmin` and `fmax`, but I also need to know how to know if the two integers are the same.

Comment: is this homework?  If so tag it as such.

Comment: You should also be aware that posting homework questions on SO is somewhat dubious.  You aren't asking for help, you're asking for an answer.  If your professor finds this it's very likely you could be removed from the university (we do so at _my_ university!)

Comment: If you can't use `>`, chances are you can't use `fmax` either :)

Comment: homework tag is obsolete, should not be used. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info

Comment: @AnalogFile saw that when I attempted to tag it as such..

Answer (score 4):

Assuming 2's complement arithmetic:

```
int intcmp(int int1, int int2)
{
    int diff=int2-int1;
    unsigned int udiff;
    memcpy(&udiff, &diff, sizeof(diff));
    if(!udiff)
        return 0;  /* the two integers are equal */
    else if(udiff & 1<<(sizeof(udiff)*CHAR_BIT-1))  /* check the sign */
        return +1;  /* int1 < int2 */
    else
        return -1;  /* int2 < int1 */
}
```

Comment: Because I never feel safe doing bitwise stuff with signed integers (*especially* manipulating the sign bit), every time I check the standard there's a new UB ready to hit. So I prefer to play it safe and just copy the result to `unsigned int` "the raw way" for safety. It may be more verbose, but at least I'm not getting nitpicked by language layers and bitten by overzealous optimizers.

Comment: you (the OP) should be aware that my answer and @MatteoItalia's answer will compile to almost *exactly* the same code :-)

Comment: @KristopherMicinski: I'm quite sure this fails for the INT_MAX/INT_MIN combo too, going into UB into the subtraction like yours.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
(num1-num2) ? ((num1-num2) & (MAX_INT+1) ? NEGATIVE : POSITIVE) : EQUAL
```

Comment: Look up how the ternary operator ?: works.  (test) ? a : b.  If test is true, a is evaluated, if false, b is evaluated.  In this case, if num1-num2 is zero, then what is true?  Use the same reasoning to figure out the inner case.

Comment: that's a good point, and you're absolutely correct.  I wrote this one because it's faster than yours, but to avoid UB I'd stick with yours.

Comment: I'm quite sure that any decent compiler, as you said, will generate the same code anyway... :)

Comment: Fails for num1 == INT_MAX and num2 == INT_MIN anyway.

Comment: as long as it can do constant folding, yes, it will.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "differentiate"?  You can't cause two numbers to select two different execution paths without some sort of branch operation, but you could in theory load an array with function pointers and manipulate the numbers to select different array elements to call (and a call is a form of branch).

You could somewhat more easily load an array with two different character string pointers, and select which to print based on which number you get.

You can convert a number to 0 or 1 based on whether it's odd or even by ANDing with 1, eg.  You can determine if numbers are equal by subtracting them and seeing if you get zero or not.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to generate a mask

```
signed int x = ...;
signed int y = ...;
mask = (x - y) >> 31;
```

So `mask` is `-1` if y>x, and is `0` otherwise (but be careful of overflow).  You can then use `&`, `|`, and `~` to build your result using this mask.